# How to query the last value across different pods

Tags: prometheus, monitoring

I have a service to collect projects' test coverage data from their pull-requests, it was put into different pods internally by the collector. So the data will be like:

example input data:

```
test_coverage{project="a", pod="pod-a"} 80@1684921872
                                        82@1684921882
test_coverage{project="a", pod="pod-b"} 90@1684982920
```

How can I get the last coverage value across different pods, so that I can get the value 90.

I tried `last_over_time(test_coverage{project="a"}[1w])` but get 2 results with

```
test_coverage{project="a", pod="pod-a"} 82
test_coverage{project="a", pod="pod-b"} 90
```

My expectation is only the 90 be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps:

1. Remove `pod` label. It can be done with aggregation by/without. For your example I'd use `max by (project) (test_coverage{project="a"})`
2. Take last value of aggregation with `last_over_time`. Notice that since argument is not a instant selector you need ti use [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) syntax.

Resulting query would look like this:

```
last_over_time((max by (project) (test_coverage{project="a"}))[1w:])
```